# Strange Class Not Found Error Java?

Tags: java, linux, deployment, build

Hey so I am trying to build and deploy a Java application.

My buildAndDeploy.sh file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# CoreSystemsAccumulator build and deploy script

echo "Building and Deploying CoreSystemsAccumulator"

# Step 1 - do a git pull.
cd ..
git pull

# Step 2 - Set CLASSPATH.
export CLASSPATH=libs/*

# Step 3 - Compile all sources using javac.
find ./src -name *.java > sources_list.txt
javac -d bin -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" @sources_list.txt
rm -rf sources_list.txt

# Step 4 - Run the app.
cd /opt/repositories/CoreSystemsAccumulator/bin
java com.ra.mainn.StartAccumulator
```

It compiles fine, but when it tries to run the app, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ra.mainn.StartAccumulator
```

Now what is really strange is when I try and run the app without the script, by just going into the bin directory and running the following command, it runs fine.

```
java com.ra.mainn.StartAccumulator
```

I am using Java 8 and on Fedora.

Any ideas will be great.
Thanks.

Comment: If you `export CLASSPATH=libs/*` and then cd into bin and run the `java` command, does it still works?

Comment: Your script is also running the `bin` directory?

Comment: Oh actually no that doesnt work if i do that, why is that the case?

Comment: I think the commandline for java applications is "java myApp.jar", the main class name is found in the metainfo.

Comment: You are setting the `CLASSPATH` to `libs/*` which does not include the `bin/` directory. It may work when the current directory is the `bin` directory and the current directory is silently added to the class path.

Comment: @Binkan Salaryman: if you want to run a jar file, the command line is `java -jar myApp.jar`, but before you can do that, you have to create the jar file with the proper meta-info.

Comment: Quote the file name pattern. `find ./src -name "*.java" > sources_list.txt`

Comment: Verify com/ra/mainn/StartAccumulator.class file present. Could be compilation issue....just a possibility

Answer (score 0):

You should add current directory to classpath after the command for changing directory (`cd /opt/repositories/CoreSystemsAccumulator/bin` ).

Probabably sth like following:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are overriding CLASSPATH. Set CLASSPATH correctly to append your libs. Ex.

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar
export CLASSPATH
```